# Disable weekends in magento date picker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento-1.7

I would like to disable the weekend (saturday and sunday) in Magento default date picker.
Is it possible in magento date picker?

Also i would like to disable the some other day's based on the store holiday's.
So is this options as possible to do in Magento date picker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tried this but this is a guide to helps you

Calendar used by magento is located here : /js/calendar/calendar.js

and from its header you find that it is done by dynarch.com

You will see there is built in functionality (via a callback) to disable dates.
(http://www.dynarch.com/jscal/#sec8)

it seems you can do this in following ways :

```
Calendar.setup({
    cont: "sample1",
    min: 20090408,
    max: 20091225
});
```

OR

```
Calendar.setup({
    cont: "sample2",
    disabled: function(date) {
        if (date.getDay() == 5) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

To extend magento calendar creation, you need to create your own class, which extends the core Varien_Data_Form_Element_Date class

You will need to override the getElementHtml() method, which contains the calandar setup script code and include the callback and dates you have, as per the calendar docs.

Please check and revert if this helps.

Comment: I Have tried to implement datepicker as per your instruction(http://www.dynarch.com/jscal/#sec8).But nothing seems to works. it seems this error message  'TypeError: de.__ is undefined in jcal2.js line65'. Could you please tell me what was the issues?

Comment: I Could not able to download the source file of this date picker.

Comment: I think this is not publicly available now, also you have to tweak into /js/calendar/calendar.js of your installation.

Comment: Ok, But already i have used the /js/calendar/calendar.js for my site.Is this possible in disable the weekends in /js/calendar/calendar.js ? Any Help Much appreciation!

Comment: I am sure this is possible, but as i haven't tried this.. not sure how much time this will take.. need a look around.. will check if i get time from regular work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
$( "#date_pickrer_id" ).datepicker({
  beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
});
```

you can also hide them using css.

```
th.ui-datepicker-week-end,
td.ui-datepicker-week-end {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if solved, however, for disabling weekends this could be tried:

```
if((date.getDay() == 5) || (date.getDay() == 0 )){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
```